# Stuck on estimation for the time complexity

Tags: time-complexity

Time complexity O(n*m) is estimated for

```
 for i ← 0 to n do 
  for j ← 0 to m do 
    STATEMENT1; 
  end for 
 end for
```

So, about this algorithm

```
 for i ← 0 to n do 
   for j ← 0 to l do 
    STATEMENT1; 
   end for 
   for k ← 0 to m-l do 
    STATEMENT2; 
   end for 
 end for
```

Because time requirements for processing STATEMENT1 and STATEMENT2 are different. If we define time for processing STATEMENT1 = O(1) and time for processing STATEMENT2 = Q(1)
We can estimate the time complexity of this algorithm is n[O[l]+Q[m-l]] or O(n*l) + Q(n*(m-1))

Please help to check my solution or can anyone help to make the solution more simple!

Comment: How about **you** estimate the time complexity, and explain why you think that's the case? We can then offer suggestions about why it isn't what you think, or confirm that you've gotten it right. As written now, you're asking us to do your assignment for you, and I'm quite certain your instructor wants to see **your** work and not ours.

Comment: Thanks @KenWhite,

I have edited the content again for the discussion!

Answer (score 3):

It is `O(n * l + n * (m - l)) = O(n * m)`

I assume that $l < m$. Otherwise it reduces to your first question.

Comment: I understand that the time complexity should be simplified, but if the time requirements for processing STATEMENT1 and STATEMENT 2 are different. Can your solution still be right?

Comment: @ThienLuan You can modify this accordingly. Say if `STATEMENT1` takes `T1` time and `STATEMENT2` takes `T2` time, then it is `O(n * l * T1 + n * (m - l) * T2)`, but if their complexity is independent of `n,m,l`, this is still correct.

Comment: Thanks Henry! This's such a good solution!

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider `STATEMENT1` takes `k1` *(constant)* time to execute, similarly `STATEMENT2` takes `k2` *(constant)* time to execute.

Now, let's do some maths:

**STATEMENT1:**

Total number of times `STATEMENT1` will be executed, `n.l`. Therefore, total time taken by it = `n.l.k1`.

---

**STATEMENT2:**

Total number of times `STATEMENT2` will be executed, `n.(m-l)`. Thus total time taken by it =
`n.(m-l).k2`.

Now, the total time taken by an algorithm will be:

```
=> n.l.k1 + n.(m-l).k2
=> n.(l.k1 + (m-l).k2)
=> n.(l.k1 + m.k2 - l.k2)
=> n.(m.k2 + l.(k1 - k2))

Now separate these two equations out and apply big_O notation onto them

=> n.m.k2        +         n.l.(k1 - k2)    (Apply Big O notation)
  since k2 is             since k1-k2 is
   constant                 constant

=> O(n.m)  +   O(n.l)  -eq(i)
```

Time to split **eq(i)** into 3 cases as follows:

**CASE 1:** `m >>> l`
Then `(n.m)` will take over the `(n.l)`
And, the final equation will become as `O(n.m)`

**CASE 2:** `l >>> m`
Then `(n.l)` will take over the `(n.m)`
And, the final equation will become as `O(n.l)`.

**CASE 3:** `l ≈ m`

```
=> O(n.m)  +   O(n.l) 
=> O(n.m)  +   O(n.m)  Since l ≈ m
=> 2.O(n.m)            Since we are dealing with Big O thus we can eliminate a prefix 2
=> O(n.m)
```